# Any php file is not working in browser

Tags: php, browser, nginx

I have tried many php files like huge file, small file but any of them is not working it will load and shows 504 gateway error

I tried test.php file with one line of code it is also showing the same error

`<?php echo"Hi working fine"; ?>`

Comment: What web server are you running this one?

Comment: i am using nginx @Matt

Comment: have you installed and configured your fastcgi server? nginx by itself does not execute PHP-scripts

Comment: Please post more information about your environment.

Comment: i have tried all things mentioned in the stackoverflow like changes in php.ini but still it is not working and the php file is working fine from terminal when tired to run in browser it loads for long time and shows 504 gateway error @Matt

Comment: Well, the problem is that *something* isn't configured correctly, duh. Obviously we cannot tell you what that is because you have given us zero information about anything. What have you checked, what have you installed, what have you configured? Have you checked any error logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have updated php execution time in php config but what about Nginx config?
Try updating your Nginx Config :

**Step 1 :** Updates for your website test.com

```
vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com
```

**Step 2 :** Updating Execution Time

```
location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
}
```

**Step 3 :** Don't forget to reload to reflect changes

```
service php5-fpm reload
service nginx reload
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done all the changes that you mentioned but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd check in the following order:
1) If php5-fpm is running:

```
    sudo service php5-fpm status
```

if it returns the process number - try telneting it:

```
    telnet 127.0.0.1 9000
```

2) If telnet returns connected status - I'd start checking the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled if the config of your site is there. If it's there - check that the stuff is set up correspondingly...one of the examples of how to set up nginx with php-fpm is here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-14.04-lts-lemp

3) If that is ok - reload the php5-fpm and nginx and check if permissions in your site dir (typically something like /var/www/html/site.com) are set right for user www-data (the default nginx user).

If that is ok - then I can't think of anything more without seeing configs and having fingertips on machine terminal. 
Hopefully this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache and PHP 7.0. Tried a dozen solutions, which still gave me errors, and then found https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/apache-with-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04/ which worked for me. With PHP 7.0 and Apache 2 installed, and as superuser:

```
apt install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.0-fpm
a2enmod actions fastcgi alias
```

Restart Apache.
And then add the following to a copy of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` as a child of `<VirtualHost>`

```
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
            SetHandler php7-fcgi.php
            Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi virtual
            Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
            FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
    </IfModule>
```

In my case, I used a `Sites` directory in `Home` instead of `/var/www/` and also had inside :

```
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Sites
```

If using a copy of `000-default.conf` make sure to disable it with `a2disconf` and enable your copy with `a2enconf`.